# ModuleNotFoundError at /register/ No module named 'django.core.email'

Tags: django

hey guys i have bug in my django project im trying to Implementation send vertification email with custom user and api and when i register with api i get error and this is my serializer code please help me:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        User = user.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            fullname=validated_data['fullname'],
            password=validated_data['password1'],
            userid=validated_data['userid'],

        )

        sendmail(email=validated_data['email'])


        return User
    
def sendmail(email):

    subject = 'you should verify your account'
    message = f'please verify your account with this link.'
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [user.email, ]
    send_mail( subject, message, email_from, recipient_list )
```

and this is my error: ModuleNotFoundError at /register/
No module named 'django.core.email'

i got this error:
ModuleNotFoundError at /register/
No module named 'django.core.email'

Answer (score 0):

Add this Line to settings file

`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'`  read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#console-backend
did you import send_mail?? to import this in `view.py` using `from django.core.mail import send_mail` and add all settings like this

```
# settings.py

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'your-email-host.com' # your email provider's SMTP server address
EMAIL_PORT = 587 # your email provider's SMTP server port
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True # whether to use a secure TLS connection
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-email@example.com' # your email address
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-email-password' # your email password
```

Comment: hey bro i add that to my code error is fixed but email doesnt sent

Comment: if my answer is correct Add a correct signal

Comment: I am  editing my answer ,you must read the link to Know how to send email you can use `stmp` or other configrations just read the link and update the first line ``EMAIL_BACKEND`` to your configrations